# Primefaces wizard with showNavBar="false"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have remove primefaces Wizard default `Next/Back` button by adding the attribute `showNavBar="false"`  and added my own button

```
<p:wizard style="border:0" showNavBar="false" widgetVar="terminationWizard">
 ........
 ........
 ........
</p:wizard>



    <div class="divTableFooter" align="right" id="footerDivfilter2" style="width: 98.00%;">
      <p:commandButton   value="Back" onclick="PF('terminationWizard').back()" />
      <p:commandButton  value="Next" onclick="PF('terminationWizard').next();" />
    </div>
```

Now how to Hide/show  this buttons when user is first or last tab.

Using Primefaces5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your wizard a handling for enabling and disabling the buttons similar to

```
<p:wizard widgetVar"wizard"
 onback="if (PF('wizard').getStepIndex(PF('wizard').currentStep) === 1) { PF('stepBackward').disable(); } PF('stepForward').enable();"
 onnext="if (PF('wizard').getStepIndex(PF('wizard').currentStep) === 2) { PF('stepForward').disable(); } PF('stepBackward').enable();"
```

Where the buttons are named `stepBackward` and `stepForward` respectively and there are 4 tabs in the wizard (zero-based but the callbacks will be executed before the new tab index is set).

Comment: for me `wizard` should be replace by  `terminationWizard` ?

Comment: I have added as you mentioned but nothing happening i have three tab in my wizard.After putting the above code clicking Next/Back button not moving any direction only refreshing the page.Is this `===` a typo?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with your question. Your question was how to disable the buttons when entering the first or last tab and has nothing to do with moving around so my suggestions have nothing to do with moving around - did this work earlier using your code before?

Comment: Yes its working fine if i remove above code .Look Like some JS issue  with the code you mentioned above

Comment: Also You mentioned  **buttons are named stepBackward and stepForward**  It mean button ids ?

Comment: Ok button name means `widgetVar` for button components

Comment: One question when wizard page is loading at that time both button active i want back button should deactive at that time also rather than disabling button should we remove those button from page like current wizard functionality

Comment: 1: Deactivate "back" by default so it is not activated on load.

Comment: How to do it by default?

Comment: Yes but it should be in some condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96710/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-smutje).